# where to customize default mapping code in Marklogic Data Hub 5?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am using `Data Hub version 5`.

In my case a single record is distributed into 5 entities like one entity has the complete address info, one has the telephone info, one has the qualification info etc..

Each entity has a unique `ID` which will be used to create a single complete record.

I created 5 entities and using the ingestion steps(1 step for each, total 5) ingested all the records.

now I need to map all the entities to single big entity for each record, to do that I need to customize the mapping code.

As in `DHF 4.*` it was quite easy to customize the code on the quick-start UI(using content, collector, main, writer etc tabs) but in `DHF 5` where can I achieve the same?

**Update:**
There is one `custom` step, I believe that can be used to achieve same as above.
please let me know if that the right way to do or if there is any better way same as in `DHF 4`

Answer (score 2):

A custom step may be the way to go. You would have to read the 4 documents staged and then create the entity to be saved in the final database by querying those documents in the staging database.

Things could get interesting when it comes to the attachment which typically is the source document. And same with provenance. If those do not matter to you, try custom step.